# stoping a confetti animation in swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, animation, timer

I am making an app that tracks the progress of goals. once a goal is complete, hitting 100%, an animation of confetti is displayed, but it won't stop. how would I stop the confetti animation after a certain amount of time? would I use a timer?

```
 func displayConfetti() {
    //creates purple confetti
        let purpleConfetti: UIImage = UIImage(named: "purpleConfetti")!
        let emitter = Emitter.get(with: purpleConfetti)
        emitter.emitterPosition = CGPoint(x: view.frame.size.width / 2, y: -10)
        emitter.emitterSize = CGSize(width: view.frame.size.width, height: 2)
        view.layer.addSublayer(emitter)
```

this is the function that holds the displayConfetti() function.

```
 func showTrophy() {
     DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now()) {
        let popUp = TrophyPopUp()
        self.view.addSubview(popUp)
        self.displayConfetti()
        //function that stops confetti after a certain amount of time
    }
```

the previous function of showTrophy() is finally displayed in this if statement.

```
    if countingIncrement == 100 {
        countingLabel.removeFromSuperview()
        goalComplete()
        showTrophy()
    }
```

how would I solve this problem and where would I add the code? any suggestions help. thanks.

Comment: Why don't you simply remove the subview?

Answer (score 0):

```
func displayConfetti() -> Emitter {
    ...
    return emitter
}

func showTrophy() {
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now()) {
        ...
        let emitter = self.displayConfetti()
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: someTime) {
            emitter.removeFromSuperLayer()
        }
    }
}
```